# Will hibernation cause my relay to lose the Guard flag?

Tags: relays, configuration, guard, flags

My relay's outgoing traffic is limited, so I had to enable accounting. The limit hasn't been reached for a while now and recently my relay received the Guard flag.

Will this flag be lost the next time my relay goes into hibernation, turning it into a normal middle relay again?

Also, if this negatively impacts clients trying to use this Guard, is there a way to refuse the Guard flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guard flag is only given to servers that are sufficiently fast and stable [[dir-spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/ecf9d02b5bf3d17fd90630f006591768a7473c22:/dir-spec.txt#l1775)].  Stable means being available most of the time.

So yes, if your relay goes down due to hibernation this can result in your relay not getting the guard flag next time it becomes available.  Clients will deal with this and just pick new/more guards.

I am not aware of any means to refuse the guard flag.

Comment: "if your relay goes down due to hibernation this can result in your relay not getting [is something missing here?] the next time it becomes available."

Comment: Yes, it was missing the guard flag, possibly due to hibernation. :)